# The physics of flow choking

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, shock-waves

Can someone explain what happens in a fluid flow at a molecular level during flow choking.

Take for example a Rayleigh flow (flow with heat addition) what happens at a micro level which prevents a sonic to supersonic transition with heat addition and why is the sonic to supersonic transition possible with flow cooling?

Basically I am trying to understand the physics behind this ,explanations I’ve seen till now are mostly formula based. I understand that the mathematics prevent certain things and allow for certain things, but physically what is the reason?

Comment: I'm afraid that most readers of this site (including myself) are probably somewhat unfamiliar with the notion of "flow cooling".  You might have better luck if there's a way to rephrase your question in terms of the physics of the sound barrier.  (I'm pretty sure L&L vol. 6 covers supersonic flow.)

Comment: Are you referring to flow in converging and diverging channels (e.g., like a [de Laval nozzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Laval_nozzle))?

Comment: @TLDR By flow cooling I meant that the direction of heat transfer is from the flow to the outside environment. In Rayleigh flow, theoretically if we supply heat to a subsonic flow it will accelerate till sonic conditions, after which if we take heat away from the flow (what i meant by cooling) the sonic flow can accelerate to supersonic conditions

Comment: @honeste_vivere I am not sure if the physics of flow choking is the same in convergent divergent flow, Rayleigh flow (flow with heat addition)  and Fanno flow (flow with friction). For my case I’ll be glad if any one of these can be explained